# How to delete database with AWS Database Deletion Protection

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have created database with *Database Deletion Protection* feature. When I am deleting I am getting this error

> To be able to delete the database, modify the database and disable
>   deletion protection.

I dont have idea which table I should modify exactly

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't have to modify a table. You need to go back and reverse the process you used to enable deletion protection. You need to go into the RDS console, find the deletion protection setting on the database, and disable it. Then it will allow you to delete the database.

https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/09/amazon-rds-now-provides-database-deletion-protection/

Comment: Once you are on the RDS console, click on the RDS you want to delete, and then click on the modify button and go to the configuration settings.  CTRL + F 'protection', or look at the bottom left. After you disable it you can delete it the normal way.  Man they really make it a journey!

Answer (score 15):

It is a feature provided by AWS to prevent from dropping of RDS instance accidentally. You need to follow steps as follows of drop the RDS

1. Select the RDS which you want to drop
2. Click on Modify and uncheck the box "Deletion protection" available in last of the screen
3. Click on Next and Apply Immediately.
4. Click on Action and Delete the Databases
5. You need to confirm about final backup before drop and keeping of retention of old backups and In the last Please Delete Me in Search Bar to initiate the Drop process of RDS